# How to handle priorities between Gradle local dependencies?

Tags: android, google-analytics, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm currently having an issue in my Android project based on Gradle. My project has two dependencies:

```
compile project(':Library:lib1')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
```

`libGoogleAnalyticsServices` is version v3 for google analytics.

the problem is that lib1 is an old library depending on version v2 of google analytics:

```
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
```

At the end there's a conflict between both jars (even if v2 should be only visible by `lib1`) and v2 is taking over v3. In my main module I'm having missing references.

So two problems:

- Why is v2 even visible from the main module?
- Why is v2 taking over v3?

Ideally I'd like to keep v2 only visible from my `lib1` and v3 only visible from my main module.

Any idea?

Comment: Technically you can't hide the legacy analytics jar if you include lib1. At runtime lib1 requires the old jar, so it makes sense to include that, it would break the app otherwise. That is the reason why v2 is visible in your main project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Android, but I would assume that the situation is the same as for standard Java applications: You can only use one version of a particular library per application, and have to make sure that all code that ships with your application is compatible with that version.

Comment: But would it be possible to override a jar dependency in this case? E.g. exclude the older jar and only use the v3 jar?

Comment: I might end using v3 in lib1 at the end, it might be the right time. I've tried to add an exclude statement to lib1 but it looks like it doesn't support local files.